# Rendered viewport shading in blender 2.8 is low-res on Retina screens

Tags: cycles-render-engine, 3d-view

Apologies for the long post (I feel I should offer a potato).

On Retina resolution screens Blender 2.8 is rendering low-res aliased images in the viewport where it should be rendering crisp high-res images as per 2.7x.

The images below illustrate the issue:

Soft aliased edges in 2.8:

[image]

[image]

While crisp sharp edges in 2.7:

[image]
[image]

And it has nothing to do with render / preview settings / samples as they are the same in both files and final renders are fine. I think it's a glitch in the 2.8 Beta version. Can someone report it? Or is there a setting I'm missing?

Thanks
JK

Comment: "*it should be rendering crisp high-res images*" That is what final rendering is for, previews should be quick and responsive

Comment: I use the viewport render to check the quality of what the final render will be, using border rendering etc. I don't need quick, i need accurate! Just want to set it back to how it worked in 2.7x.

Answer (score 3):

This is a feature, which actually originated from using high resolution screens.
*<sup>([Other](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/97014/30849) [users](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/7073/30849) actually want to increase the pixel size.)</sup>*

With highresolution screen viewing a small portion on your display, already requires lots of pixels to be rendered. If you just want to have a rough idea of the color and shapes, you don't need a highres version.

1. Go to the *Properties* Panel.
2. Go to the *Scene* Tab (the second from top).
3. Go to the *Performance* section.
4. Go to the *Viewport* subsection.

Change the **Pixel Size** attribute to **1x**. If it is set to automatic, Blender probably realizes you are using a high resolution screen and adjust the preview pixel size for better performance.

Comment: Hi Leander, your suggestion about pixel size attribute successively halves the veiwport resolution. I'm trying to double it so it goes back to how it was in Blender 2.7x, smooth and sharp - not aliased. How do i report a bug? do you know? Thanks.

Comment: [Creating](https://developer.blender.org/maniphest/task/create/?project=2&type=Bug) with [Guidelines](https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Process/Bug_Reports).